# Validation not fired on List<> parameter of controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Here is a snippet:

```cs
public class OrderItemModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class OrderMenuModel : List<OrderItemModel>, IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("test");
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Calculate(OrderMenuModel menuItems)
{
    if (!TryValidateModel(menuItems))
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    // processing
}
```

The `Validate()` method is not called automatically, so I have to call `TryValidateModel()`. As this does help, I would assume there is nothing wrong with my `OrderMenuModel`. Also, it works when an instance of the class is a member of a containing object, as follows:

```cs
public class OrderModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public OrderMenuModel MenuItems { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // validation without calling MenuItems.Validate(), as it gets called automatically
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Place(OrderModel order)
{
    // no need to call TryValidateModel()
}
```

Can anyone figure out what happens in the first scenario? Thanks.

Comment: You are right that this is inconsistent behavior considering that TryValidateModel works. There is nothing wrong with your object model as this problem occurs whenever the root model implements IEnumerable.  I am debugging the framework source and trying to figure out why the validation in the DefaultModelBinder doesn't work here but an explicit call to TryValidateModel does.  This may be a legitimate bug.  Hope to get back to you soon but in the mean time I've deleted my previous answer to attract others who might be able to help.